# error while locating svg using xpath in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

error while locating svg in selenium using python

error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKBJp.png)/section/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKBJp.png)/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/a/svg/path

[inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKBJp.png)

Comment: Could you provide more information? Like the code that caused this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to identify `svg` using the name attribute as shown below

```
/html/body/div1/section/div/div1/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/a/*[name()='svg']/path
```